# Flash memory failure

Tags: embedded, flash-memory, lauterbach, nor

I'm working on a XScale PXA270 with NOR Flash on Chip select 0.
due to the obsolescence of the previous flash, my company change it for an AMD/Spansion compatible MX29GL128.

I'm trying to write on it using Lauterbach JTAG.

here is my script :     https://pastebin.com/jcjsbwE3

```
; reset the FLASH declaration
FLASH.CFI 0x00000000 L
; declare FLASH sectors via
; CFI query
;FLASH.CHANGEtype ALL AM29F100
; change type to AM29F100 to use "word wise" mode
FLASH.UNLOCK ALL
; unlock FLASH if required
FLASH.ReProgram ALL
; enable the FLASH for programming
;Data.LOAD.auto /home/lai/devel/uboot-2017-01/u-boot.bin
Data.LOAD.binary /tftpboot/u-boot-rioms-pxa270.bin D:0x00000000--0x1FFFF
; load the programming file
FLASH.ReProgram off
; program the FLASH and disable
; the FLASH programming
```

But get an error.

> Flash programming error around address SD:`0x7C`.

On this picture, you can see the commands on the bus and the error.

[image]

Have you some idea ? I'm stuck on it since many days

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, but more suitable for the electronics site. But the best bet is probably to contact the manufacturer. The datasheet mentions something about a command cycle.

Comment: I suggest to check your FLASH.CFI command. You are currently using a 32-bit bus width (indicated by the "L"). Maybe your new flash is connected only via 16-bits? Otherwise check if there is any write-protection active, which is not removed by the unlock, since it looks like your flash gets not programmed at all.

Comment: According to https://www.lauterbach.com/ylist.html MX29GL128 is only supported in 8-bit and 16-bit.

Comment: The MX29GL128 is a 8/16 bit flash. but we are using 2 flash to get a 32bits bus width.

This is supported by Lauterbach.

Comment: We have resolved our issue. It was the WP# pin not driven to high level.
It seems on this flash, the WP# lock all the sectors instead of locking only the locked one like in the previous one.
Thank's for support